# How to perform not equal to function using joins in 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I've two table usr and mat, here i'm trying to write a query where mat suppose to give me the result of (UID != DID) only the not equal value from mat table 
ie,) (6,'q','r'), (7,'s','t') using only joins not with Exists, NOT Exists or IN

```
create table usr ( uid int, uco varchar, umo varchar);

insert into usr (uid,uco,umo) values (1,'k','l'), (2,'m','n'), (3,'o','p'), (6,'q','r'), (7,'s','t');

create table mat( did int, co varchar, mo varchar);

insert into mat (did,co,mo) values (1,'a','f'), (2,'b','g'), (3,'c','h'), (4,'d','i'), (5,'e','j');
```

Comment: Why can't you use `Not Exists`?

Comment: @Jonny Both `<>` and `!=` are valid inequality operators in sql server.

Comment: Why can't you use `NOT EXISTS` which can be more appropriate than an `OUTER JOIN`? Read: http://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join

Answer (score 5, accepted):

May be this is what you are looking at -

```
select * from usr left outer join mat on usr.uid = mat.did where did is null
```